# In Solaris box how do we check if hyper-threading/multi-threading is enabled or not using command?

Tags: solaris, multithreading, hyperthreading

In Solaris, how we can find the status or check hyper-threading or multi-threading is enabled or not using commands?

Answer (score 2):

Use `psrinfo` command, to view info of your CPUs:

`psrinfo -vp` to view info of physical and virtual CPUs,
`psrinfo` to view online/offline CPUs.

Let's say you have 4 CPUs, including HT virtual CPUs, 0-3, and want to disable HTs. They will be presented in pairs, 1st physical will have (0,2), 2nd (1,3). 2 and 3 are the HTs.

To disable/enable:
`psradm -f 2 3` will disable them (offline).
`psrinfo` to view the online/offline CPUs (check the difference)
`psradm -n 2 3` to enable them (online).

These settings are runtime only. You must enable/disable HT through BIOS/EFI for persistence. I've tested these on Solaris 11.4 x86.

Comment: I just want to know the status no need to change. So how we can decide by looking at the cpu info.

Comment: If for example you have 2 physical CPUs and HT is enabled in BIOS/EFI, executing `psrinfo` you'll get 4 CPUs, if HT is used by Solaris. Else you'll see only 2.

Comment: Here cpu means cores right? Consider i  have set 2 cores and if we check the core count using kstat cpu_info | grep core_id | sort -u | wc -l then it would be showing 4 is it ?

Comment: Yes, correct, by CPUs I meant CPU cores. `kstat ...` command you mentioned gives me one more line, pkg_core_id, probably different output due to version. But yes, it should show you 4 core_ids (0,1, etc), equivalent to `psrinfo` output.

Comment: So how do we get the actual cpu count?

Comment: The commands I told you about, `psrinfo` total number of cpus, `psrinfo -p` or `psrinfo -vp` (verbose) physical CPUs. `prtdiag -v` also can give you info on the whole system, cpus also.